Lua get array size in object
I am attempting to make a loop that goes though each item in an array.
However, that array is in an object and the loop will only run though the first item, This is due to loop seeing the inserted value as 1.
function singStuff(membersIndex, noteData, noteType, char)
if #char.noteGroup == 0 then return end --this = 1
debugPrint(char.noteGroup)
--debugPrint(char.noteGroup[2]) --This doesn't work
for e,curNote in pairs(char.noteGroup) do --Loops once cus it counds how the number of noteGroups, not how many are in it

    --debugPrint(curNote[4]) -- #curNote = 4 (Correct)
    if noteType == curNote[e] then -- Removing these do not effect the loop -- curNote[e] works correctly
        char.doIdle = false
        playAnim(char.name, anims[noteData + 1], true)
        runTimer(("sing_cooldown_" .. char.name), 0.4, 1)
    elseif noteType == curNote[e]..char.altSuffix then
        char.doIdle = false
        playAnim(char.name, anims[noteData + 1]..char.altSuffix, true)
        runTimer(("sing_cooldown_" .. char.name), 0.4, 1)
    end
end
end

My guess is that # function is counting how many "noteGroup" arrays there are in the "char" object, rather than how many items are in the array.
I attempted "char.#noteGroup" but that doesn't work. The code in the loop works correctly, with setting "curNote[e]" to "curNote[2]" getting the correct result. Same with the other array values.
Removing the code doesn't do anything, it still only loops once.

if #char.noteGroup == 0, try next(char.noteGroup) instead, # only works for indexed 1, 2, 3, etc. tables. next will get the first member

Can you add the code where you define the char object, and where noteGroup  is set if that is in some other section of the code. being able to see the actual structure of the object will help people determine your problem. Alternatively if you can write an example that reproduces the problem with as little code as possible (this might even help you to anwser the question yourself)

From lua 5.1 ref:
next (table [, index])
"When called with the last index, or with nil in an empty table, next returns nil. If the second argument is absent, then it is interpreted as nil. In particular, you can use next(t) to check whether a table is empty. "
